# Is there is some equivalent of strip-debug for AngularJS which can remove uses of $log?

Tags: angularjs, minify

Or how do you **remove** `$log.debug` lines from your AngularJS app?

`strip-debug` is good. However it doesn't do anything with $log.

I’ve found `gulp-strip-ng-log`. However it removes all uses of `$log` and it ditched ages ago. So, I'm not gonna use it.

I know about `$logprovider.debugenabled(false)`. But I’m talking about code *minification*.

By now I'm going to use `sed` utility. But it won't be nice and universal solution.

Comment: `$logprovider.debugenabled(false);`

Comment: Nope. It doesn't remove code.

Comment: Have you tried `grunt-strip`. I've used this in one of my projects to remove `console.log` from everywhere in the build

Comment: It doesn't do anything with $log.debug